# Unload or emptying data from previous AJAX query before making second request is submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, object

I'm creating a small web app for pilots and flight dispatchers that will enable them to have headwind and crosswind automatically calculated for every runway at a given airport. I need to iterate through the data I received as a Javascript object from an AJAX request, and so far, it works for the first one. But when I resubmit the form, it's like the javascript object does not get unloaded or something similar.

ex.: let's say I first make a request for an airport with 9 different winds in the forecast, all is good and I can iterate from index 0 to 8 no problem,  then when I make a second request for another airport with only let's say.. 3 winds in its forecast, I will be able to cycle through index 0 to 2 of the second airport no problem, but when I then press Next again, it shows me the fourth index (so winds) of the first airport. Also, as you'll see in the code, I inserted some console.log to try and figure out what happens with the counters.. and while I do have 4 for the first one which is normal (I will most likely combine everything eventually within a single one), I end up with 8 after the second request, 12 after the third, etc.

I would like to tackle it by myself in order to learn but I don't even know where the problem is right now..

Here's my JS code: https://gist.github.com/richaard0/a5a0f67ad8bac6154021b7a143f8b70f
(it's quite lenghty so I figured you might prefer an external link).

And also an image of my console logs. (apologies for the awful drawing)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VomT1.png

I'm still very green with Javascript (and programming in general, I started 2 months ago with HarvardX CS50), so bear with me please.

Comment: *"so I figured you might prefer an external link"* - You were mistaken.  Please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  If the code is too long to meaningfully include in the question, then it's too long to minimally demonstrate the problem.  Please narrow down the problem to something more specific that can be included and demonstrated in the question.  Your browser's debugging tools can be very helpful for this.

Comment: From votes: "*Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.*" - have a read of [mcve]

Comment: The reason for providing *minimal* code here is that it makes you think about exactly what is causing the problem.  If you have 150 lines of code and "a problem" then you haven't determined the *cause*.  So you remove the parts that you know work and parts that are similar to others, eg remove all the verbose class changes (look at `$("#id").addClass()`) / replace the ajax call with known data / only have a single counter/index (not 4).  This will narrow down your code substantially and, if you go far enough, leave you with a few lines of code that will help to show you where the problem lies.

Comment: @freedomn-m It was inside `$.post` before and the behaviour was the same, it was only me trying things out in desperation. I also just tried it again to confirm and the behaviour is the same.

Comment: Also, I do realize that posting shorter code is encouraged and I also do realize I haven't determined the cause. That's precisely my problem, I can't figure out what is causing it. I've been "okay-ish" so far at finding solutions once I figured out what a problem is, and to be honest, I don't even want a solution lol, I just need help pinpointing where things are going wrong. 

I'll try to be more concise next time.

Comment: Just providing FYI for close votes, not judging

Comment: I missed the `if (counter1 <` checks due to the lack of indenting, so you're right, wouldn't matter for viewing the wrong data, but would still need to be reset in the case where you're already `counter>length`

Comment: Can you confirm the data you're retrieving doesn't include the old data?  What's in `/?station=`

Comment: @freedomn-m yes, when I expand the console logs, I see the data I requested being added below the results of `console.log(counter1);, console.log(counter2);, etc`  and it doesn't contain any other data than the one being requested.